# Calculating the power in bash

Tags: bash

I'm pretty new to bash scripting. I'm  trying to work out calculations, and what I'm specifically trying to do is write a script that allows me to enter a parameter, and that my script calculates the power of 2 to that parameter.

So say I would try

```
bash scriptname 3
```

My script would calculate `2^3=8`

I'm trying with

```
(( 2 ^ $1 ))
```

but that's not doing anything. Is there a command to calculate the power of something that I'm not aware of?

Comment: `^` is a `xor` operator

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The power operator in bash is `**`

Example:

```
echo $((2 ** 4))
16
```

Comment: You might add the let command to your script to convert them to numbers

Comment: @ojblass, the arithmetic expansion syntax `$(( ... ))` is equivalent to `let`, and often more convenient. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion

Comment: But I assume he will be passing in $1 and $2.  If this syntax takes those as arguments so be it.  I'm not booted into Linux right now.

Comment: @ojblass Yes the arguments can be used in this syntax. Note that you must use the dollar sign for arguments, but the dollar can be ommited in the arithemtic expansion for variables. E.g `((a + b))` works, but you need the dollar for the argument like `(($1 + $2))`.

Comment: How to calculate 10^-2, (which is 0.01)

Comment: @ShichengGuo: Bash doesn't handle floats, you should use an external tool such as bc: `bc -l <<< '10^-2'`

Answer (score 7):

It is worth pointing out that you'd observe overflow when the result starts to exceed `LONG_MAX`:

```
$ echo $((2**62))
4611686018427387904
$ echo $((2**63 - 1))
9223372036854775807
$ echo $((2**63))
-9223372036854775808
```

(Observe the result when the value exceeds 2<sup>63</sup>-1)

You might instead want to use something that allows arbitrary precision arithmetic since you might hit that limit rather fast if computing powers.  For example, you could use `bc` (and it'd let you use `^` too!):

```
$ bc <<< 2^63
9223372036854775808
$ bc <<< 2^128
340282366920938463463374607431768211456
$ BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc <<< 2^1024
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun you can also use bitwise shifts (of course this only works for a base that is a power of a power of 2):

```
echo $((1<<$1))
```

Make sure you read devnull's caveat about overflows.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are entirely correct, and if you are working with integer values represent the best way to do this kind of calculation.  But it is worth noting that [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic does not deal with non-integer values.

If you require non-integer arithmetic like this, you can use the `bc` utility.  e.g if you need to take the 3rd power of 2.5, you can do this:

```
$ bc <<< "scale=10; 2.5 ^ 3"
15.625
$
```

Note setting the `scale` builtin variable sets the number of decimal places calculations should be given in.

Comment: Instead of fiddling with `scale`, the `-l` switch might be preferable.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yep, `-l` has the side-effect of setting scale to 20, if that is the precision you require.