# Bash take variable to a power

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble using online references to solve this, I need to take a power of a variable as an argument like so:

```
for i in `seq 0 4`
do
    ... --chunk_size=$((awk `BEGIN{print 10^$i}`))
done
```

But this does not work and gives me an error, how can I do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044728/calculating-the-power-in-bash

Answer (score 5):

Simply use Bash with `**`

```
for i in {0..4}
do
    ... --chunk_size="$(( 10 ** i ))"
done
```

Example:

```
$ for i in {0..4}; do echo "$(( 10 ** i ))"; done
1
10
100
1000
10000
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `bc`:

```
for i in {0..4}; do bc -l <<<"10^$i"; done
1
10
100
1000
10000
```

using `awk`:

```
for i in {0..4}; do awk 'BEGIN{print 10^'$i'}'; done
1
10
100
1000
10000
```

So your code could look like this:

```
for i in `seq 0 4`
do
    ... --chunk_size=$(bc -l <<< "10^$i")
done
```

or

```
for i in `seq 0 4`
do
    ... --chunk_size=$(awk 'BEGIN{print 10^'$i'}')
done
```

Answer (score 0):

use `-v` option for pass `bash` variable to `awk`

```
for i in `seq 0 4`
do
    chunk_size=$(awk -v"i=$i" 'BEGIN{print 10^i}');
    echo $chunk_size
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
```